# YouTube app holds a long wakelock. What app settings can I change to keep it from doing this?

Tags: battery, youtube, htc-evo, wakelock

I am using an HTC Evo 4g with Android 2.3.5 Gingerbread. I'm trying to deal with apps which keep my phone from entering sleep mode, and the YouTube app is a major offender. With downloaded apps, usually the fix is to remove the app and find an alternative app that doesn't suck the battery dry. But I want to keep YouTube enabled so I can watch YouTube videos.

What settings for the YouTube app can I change to get it to not hold a wake lock for hours on end? Are there any device settings that I can change to help?

So far I have disabled "Preload subscriptions", "Preload watch later", "Improve YouTube", and "Notifications" in the YouTube app's settings, but the wake lock still occurs.

Comment: `adb shell appops set <pkg> WAKE_LOCK ignore`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Wakelock Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector)** in combination with **[Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en)** to block wakelocks and save a lot of battery.

**Update:** Since Gingerbread is not supported by Greenify, you can use [**Wakelock Terminator**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.andro.wlt) to stop the wakelocks *if you have root*.