# Kaspersky Who Calls app keeps the phone screen on

Tags: screen, java, wakelock

There's an app called [Anti-spam: Kaspersky Who Calls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaspersky.who_calls).

The problem with this app is that when someone calls you the app shows the caller information in a popup and if you don't dismiss the said popup, the phone screen will never turn off. Imagine you got a call and you couldn't answer it, you forget about it and later you realize the whole time the screen has been on and your battery is almost dead.

I know there's a thing called "[Wake Lock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock)" but it's all alien to me and I've no idea what to look for. I've used decompiler.com and got [this](https://www.decompiler.com/jar/65feb667f8e64322a1ae586211b5188a/Anti-spam_%20Kaspersky%20Who%20Calls_1.47.0.80_Apkpure.apk) but while grepping through the sources I wasn't able to find `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, so it could have been done differently or this service doesn't decode this flag correctly.

I've found this:

```
    public static final long WAKE_LOCK_MAX_ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT_MS = 600000;

    @SuppressLint({"Wakelock"})
    public void run() {
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
        if (h(this.f12161a)) {
            this.f12162a.acquire(Constants.WAKE_LOCK_ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
        }
```

It probably results in the screen being on for 10 minutes, not indefinitely but it's also excessive.

I wonder if it could be the culprit.

Comment: Related/possibly dupe: [YouTube app holds a long wakelock. What app settings can I change to keep it from doing this?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/90154/44325). While non-development solutions are on-topic here, please note that code-related like reverse-engineering is off-topic here but should be on-topic on [reverseengineering.se].